# Non-zero based multidimensional arrays

Tags: c#, excel, multidimensional-array, com, interop

I am extracting cells out of a spreadsheet using the `Interopt.Excel` API. When I call:

`object[,] rangeValues = (object[,])range.get_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);`

And set a breakpoint and inspect `rangeValues`, I see elements starting at [1,1] "foo", [1,2] "bar", etc.

However, if I do `string[,] test = new string[2, 2] { { "one", "two" }, { "three", "four" } };`

The elements start at [0,0]. How does the Excel API construct a multidimensional array w/ empty elements? I tried adding null but you still have an [0,0] entry. Their object doesn't show that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CLR supports non-zero based arrays. They are confusing and to be avoided. I believe, the COM interop marshaller can create them.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301755.aspx

> Common Language Specification (CLS) compliance requires that all
>   arrays be zero-based. This allows a method written in C# to create an
>   array and pass the array's reference to code written in another
>   language such as Visual Basic®. In addition, since zero-based arrays
>   are by far the most common, Microsoft has spent a lot of time
>   optimizing their performance. However, the CLR does support
>   non-zero-based arrays but they are discouraged. For those of you who
>   do not care about performance and cross-language portability, I will
>   demonstrate how to create and use non-zero-based arrays later in this
>   section.

This is the first time I have seen one in real-world code.

Apparently, multi-dimensional arrays have the same type no matter whether they are zero-based or not. Single-dimensional ones have a different type. Makes sense because if they had the same type the JIT would always have to produce slow code for the general case.

[image]

Comment: I thought non-zero indexed arrays couldn't use the array notation in C#?  Shouldn't the cast to `object[,]` fail?

Comment: They cannot be created in C# but you can create them using factory methods. They have the same type as zero-based ones. Non-SZ arrays have, according to the SSCLI source, extra data as part of the object that stores meta-data. It comes before the element data. I personally find their existence to be concerning. Might even trigger security-relevant bugs in BCL code. I mean who thinks of arrays that start at -1?!

Comment: @Servy Apparently, multi-dimensional arrays have the same type, but single-dimensional ones do not. See the edit. And another useless piece of extremely specialized knowledge was added to my brain...

Comment: That's messed up.  I knew that I had heard that one-indexed arrays couldn't use C# array notation, just didn't know it applied only to single dimensional arrays.